# Transaction - Commit after user confirm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, transactions

I have a method where the user changed many fields and save the result.
During updating process (transactional), it's necessary to do many checks if others process are afected by the changes. If this occurs, it is necessary to request user confirmation before proceeding with the process. If it confirms the commit of the transaction is performed, otherwise rollback is required.

It' not possible to perform these validations without changing the tables in question, since these changes have a direct impact on the necessary validations.

Is it possible to keep an open transaction in the bank until user confirmation? How to do this using Asp .Net MVC and TransactionScope (Oracle DataBase)?

Comment: What kind of checks are you talking about?

Comment: For example ... After updating the user changes in the database, I run a complex select in the database, considering the table already changed. If in this select a specific condition is returned, it is necessary to show to the user the other affected records, so that it confirms or not the change.

Comment: When you make changes, then any SELECT (in that session) will see already changed data. No matter if data is COMMITed or not.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. While the commit is not performed, the selects from another session still see the old data. No?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Ok if in the same session. But how can I keep a session open and send a confirmation request to View?

Comment: That will be difficult and is actually in contradiction to basic principles of "transaction" concept.